# wanted to change build process in angular-seed repository

Tags: angular, angular-seed

Reference: https://github.com/mgechev/angular-seed

I need help with the following question: I have a custom asset structure to I decided to format and separate my file types by folder:

```
/img
/scss
/ts
/fonts
```

So I had to change in seed.config.ts the path names:

```
 ASSETS_SRC = `${this.APP_SRC}/assets`;

  /**
   * The folder of the applications img files.
   * @type {string}
   */
  IMG_SRC = `${this.ASSETS_SRC}/img`;

  /**
   * The folder of the applications ts files.
   * @type {string}
   */
  TS_SRC = `${this.ASSETS_SRC}/ts`;

  /**
   * The folder of the applications fonts files.
   * @type {string}
   */
  FONT_SRC = `${this.ASSETS_SRC}/fonts`;
```

I wanted to know if under tasks/project folder for a new task I have to call it the same name as the original task "build.assets.dev.ts, build.assets.prod.ts" to overwrite it and add it to tasks/project folder?

Like so:

```
import * as gulp from 'gulp';
import { join } from 'path';

import { AssetsTask } from '../assets_task';
import Config from '../../config';

/**
 * Executes the build process, copying the assets located in `src/client` over to the appropriate
 * `dist/dev` directory.
 */
export =
  class BuildAssetsTask extends AssetsTask {
    run(done: any) {
      let paths: string[] = [
        join(Config.APP_SRC, '**'),
        join(Config.NPM_BASE, '@angular', 'service-worker', 'bundles', 'worker-basic.js'),
        '!' + join(Config.TS_SRC, '**', '*.ts'),
        '!' + join(Config.SCSS_SRC, '**', '*.scss'),
        '!' + join(Config.IMG_SRC, '**', '*.jpg|png|gif|svg|jpeg'),
        '!' + join(Config.FONT_SRC, '**', '*.eot|woff|otf|ttf'),
            ].concat(Config.TEMP_FILES.map((p) => { return '!' + p; }));

      return gulp.src(paths)
        .pipe(gulp.dest(Config.APP_DEST));
    }
  };
```